# How to create new generation of turtles every 10 ticks?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to do the following in NetLogo:

1. I create, using a slider for each breed, 100 turtles with breed A and 100 turtles with breed B
2. Ask turtles with breed A and breed B move randomly, etc.
3. After 10 ticks, turtles with breed A and B die (managed to make this work)
4. Create/generate new 100 turtles with breed A and B, move randomly, etc.
5. Repeat step 3

Basically, I would like to ask the old generation of turtles to die after 10 ticks and create new generation of 100 turtles breed A and 100 turtles breed B. How could this be repeated automatically every 10 ticks for a number of ticks (e.g. 3000)?

Your help is much appreciated.

Here is part of the code:

```
breed [ honest-citizen honest-citizens ]
breed [ potential-offender potential-offenders  ]

…

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  ask patches [ set pcolor black ]

  set-default-shape honest-citizen "circle"
  create-honest-citizen initial-number-honest-citizens ;;create honest citizens then initialise their variables
  [
    set color white
    set size 0.2
    set income income-from-work
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set birth-tick ticks
  ]

  set-default-shape potential-offender "circle"
  create-potential-offender initial-number-potential-offenders
  [
    set color red + 1
    set size 0.2
    ;; set income a random number between two extremes using formula
    ;; random (max-extreme - min-extreme + 1) + min-extreme
    set income random ((income-from-work + alfa-constant) - (income-from-work - alfa-constant) + 1) + (income-from-work - alfa-constant)
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set birth-tick ticks
  ]

  set-default-shape government-agent "circle"
  create-government-agent initial-number-law-enforcement-agents
  [
    set color yellow + 1
    set size 0.2
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

end

to go
 if not any? turtles [ stop ]
 if ticks > 3000 [ stop ]


 ask government-agent [
    count-number-of-workers
    count-number-of-criminals
    calculate-tax-per-worker
    calculate-probability-of-conviction
    move
  ]

  ask potential-offender [
    move
    set net-income income
    ;; if decide to become criminal then commit crime, else work legally and pay tax
    decide-commit-crime
    death ;; occurs when arrested and after 10 periods of time
  ]

  ask honest-citizen [
    move
    set net-income income-from-work
    pay-tax
    death ;; after 10 periods of time
  ]

  tick
end

…

to move
  rt random 50
  rt random 50
  fd 1
end

to death
  if ticks - birth-tick > 10 [
  die
  ]
end
```

Comment: You need to share some code thanks, so we can see how far you've got, and how to respond to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want something to happen "every *n* ticks", you can usually use [`mod`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#mod). Here is a complete example:

```
breed [ as a ]
breed [ bs b ]

globals [
  ; those would be sliders in your model
  number-of-as
  number-of-bs
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set number-of-as 100 
  set number-of-bs 100
  create-as number-of-as 
  create-bs number-of-bs
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if ticks > 0 and ticks mod 10 = 0 [ ; <--- this is the important line
    ask as [ die ]
    ask bs [ die ]
    create-as number-of-as 
    create-bs number-of-bs
  ]
  ask as [ move ]
  ask bs [ move ]
  tick
end

to move
  rt random 50
  lt random 50
  fd 1
end
```

I have added a `ticks > 0` clause so that turtles don't get killed/regenerated on the first tick, but you tweak this as you like.

Comment: Thank you! It works just as I wanted. If I leave if ticks > 0 and mod 10 = 0 then the result is just what I wanted. I just had to add again the random coordinates and the other properties for when creating new agents, otherwise the agents would be created in a cluster every 10 ticks. Hope that will not affect the way the simulation works.